# Contradiction for primes of the form $p = x^2 + 2y^2 \implies x^2 \equiv -2 \mod p$?

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Jarvis book on Algebraic Number Theory exercise 1.9, states that any prime of the form $p = x^2 + 2y^2 \implies x^2 \equiv -2 \mod p$.

> Exercise 1.9 Prove that an odd prime $p$ can be written as $x^2 + 2y^2$ with $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the congruence $x^2 \equiv -2 \mod p$ is soluble.

But the numbers $x = 910833, y = 840626$ seem to contradict this.

```
sage: y = 840626
sage: x = 910833
sage: p = x^2 + 2*y^2
sage: is_prime(p)
True
sage: (x^2 + 2) % p
829616753891
```

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: it means $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, it is different $x$ in $x^2 \equiv -2 \mod p$

Comment: In this case notice that $141238812168^2 \equiv -2 \pmod {829616753891}$

Comment: Good case lesson in notation:  never use the same variable to denote multiple things in the same context.  Guaranteed to create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by the people in the comments for this question. The $x$ is a different variable (not the same).